# Communications link failure Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I am trying to connect to MySql db using hibernate from my java application. When i deploy the war on one of our servers, i am getting the below exception though it works when i deploy it locally on my machine. Network connectivity is also not the issue since i successfully tried pinging the db from the server.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 600,902 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 600,902 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor230.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3851)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2471)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2728)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5075)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:89)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3832)
... 38 more

at com.shc.ecom.rx.batch.scheduler.RunSchedulerPoc.run(RunSchedulerPoc.java:63)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor180.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The answers so far on this question doesn't seem to solve my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This happens when a hibernate object retrieved in a session stays ideal for long time because some other tasks are been done which doesn't require DB transactions. As there is no communication to DB server for long time and then if some transaction is done using same session, this exception is thrown. Try increasing wait timeout and check.

Comment: pinging the db machine from the server means that the db machine is up and accessible. It does not guarantee that DB is up. If you have a sql client on the server then try connecting to the db from the server to your db with the same credentials as used in the web application.

Comment: Db is up since i am able to access from my local machine. I don't have mysql client on the server so can't check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after i added the following property to my hibernate configuration, it was missing earlier :

hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=300

You can read about it on :

https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/

Comment: Setting timeout (&Co) parameters is OK.  Not controlled scenarios in webapp are not OK.